# Word saving insertions but not deletions

Tags: ms-word

I'm having a weird problem with Word. Yesterday I opened a manuscript I'd been editing using Track Changes, only to find that some of my edits had saved but not others. For example, if I'd changed 'the' to start with a capital, the document would now be showing 'tThe' (this was without Tracked Changes showing). Words that I'd changed to be hyphenated were showing the hyphen but with the space that had originally been between the two words as well, and some changes that I'd made to styles didn't seem to have been saved.

I put it down to some weird oddity and went through the manuscript again yesterday, but this morning I opened it to find that once again some of my changes hadn't been saved. I took out some italics, and my comment (added yesterday) explaining the change was still there but so were the italics and I definitely remember taking them out.

I'm using Word 2016.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!!

I have tried viewing on all different levels of mark up and tried accepting all changes but none of them are showing the deletions (by which I mean, the deleted letters are still visible). The changes were definitely showing up the first time I made them - they just seem to have got lost somehow during saving or re-opening the document. I've checked Advanced Track Changes Options and deletions are marked as strikethrough.